# How to change setter properties on ResourceDictionary in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have `<ContentPage.Resources>` and few setters and I want when I check the weather condition to change the font color from white to black in c# code in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` the code in xaml page look like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="labelStyle"
               TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" 
                    Value="Medium" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" 
                    Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" 
                    Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                    Value="White"/>
        </Style>

        <local:LongToDateTimeConverter x:Key="longToDateTimeConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

How to get `<Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>` and how to change its color to black in c# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no enough info, but I assume you can use [data triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers)  to achieve your end goal which is dynamically changing `TextColor` based on some data (property).

```
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">

            <Setter Property="FontSize" 
                    Value="Medium" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" 
                    Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" 
                    Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                    Value="White"/>

    <Style .Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                     Binding="{Binding Source=...,
                                       Path=...}"
                     Value="0">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color from `MainPage.xaml.cs`, you can use slightly changed @Cfun's proposed suggestion, and instead of hard coding the value in XAML, you can add binding object to your `Setter.Value` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StyleColorChange.MainPage"
             x:Name="MyPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="labelStyle"
               TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" 
                    Value="Medium" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" 
                    Value="0,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" 
                    Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                 Binding="{Binding isWeatherConditionChecked}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding labelStyleTextColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <!--This part is only to create a sample app-->
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <Button Text="Go!" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
        <Label x:Name="MyLabel" Text="This is a label" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And in `MainPage.xaml.cs` you can have something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StyleColorChange
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string labelStyleTextColor { get; set; } = "White";
        private bool _isWeatherConditionChecked;
        public bool isWeatherConditionChecked
        {
            get { return _isWeatherConditionChecked; }
            set { _isWeatherConditionChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("isWeatherConditionChecked"); }
        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            labelStyleTextColor = "Black";
            isWeatherConditionChecked = !isWeatherConditionChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

I added `isWeatherConditionChecked` and `labelStyleTextColor` just for the example, but I guess you have something similar in your code that you can use.